# How can I split commas and periods from words inside of string using split?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am trying to change specific word in a string with something else. For example,  I want to change 'John' in `let name = 'Hi, my name is John.';` to 'Jack'.

I know how to split a string by words or characters. I also know how to remove commas, periods, and other symbols in a string. However, if I split the given string with a separator (" "), I will have 'John.' which I do not want. (I know I can switch 'John.' with 'Jack.' but assume that I have an key and value pairs in an object and I am using the values which are names {Father: Jack, Mother: Susan, ...}

I don't know how to separate a string word by word including commas and periods.

For example, if I was given an input which is a string:
`'Hi, my name is John.'`

I want to split the input as below:
`['Hi', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'John', '.']`

Does anyone know how to do it?

Below is the challenge I am working on.

> Create a function censor that accepts no arguments. censor will return a function that will accept either two strings, or one string. When two strings are given, the returned function will hold onto the two strings as a pair, for future use. When one string is given, the returned function will return the same string, except all instances of a first string (of a saved pair) will be replaced with the second string (of a saved pair).

```
//Your code here

const changeScene = censor();
changeScene('dogs', 'cats');
changeScene('quick', 'slow');
console.log(changeScene('The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.')); // should log: 'The slow, brown fox jumps over the lazy cats.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your real question is "How do I replace a substring with another string?"

Checkout the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
let inputString = "Hi, my name is John.";
let switch1 = ["John", "Jack"];
let switched = inputString.replace(switch1[0], switch1[1]);
console.log(switched); // Hi, my name is Jack.
```

---

UPDATE: If you want to get ALL occurrences (`g`), be case insensitive (`i`), and use boundaries so that it isn't a word within another word (`\\b`), you can use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
let inputString = "I'm John, or johnny, but I prefer john.";
let switch1 = ["John", "Jack"];
let re = new RegExp(`\\b${switch1[0]}\\b`, 'gi');
console.log(inputString.replace(re, switch1[1])); // I'm Jack, or johnny, but I prefer Jack.
```

Comment: Oh my god... I totally forgot about replace method... I feel so dumb now. Thank you so much @JBallin I really appreciate your help

Comment: Glad I could help! I just learned about it now actually--pretty cool. I tried to boil down what you were really asking, and then googled "replace string javascript".

Comment: @sgt.ahn - see my update. also, if you want more practice check out this codewars problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-fun-number-283-censor-the-forbidden-words/train/javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can Try This ...

```
 var string = 'Hi, my name is John.';
//var arr = string.split(/,|\.| /);
var arr = string.split(/([,.\s])/);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `'Hi, my name is John.'.split(/[,. ]/);` will do the job. It will split commas and periods and spaces.

Edit: For those who want to keep the comma and period, here is my wildly inefficient method.

```js
var str = 'Hi, my name is John.'
str = str.replace('.', 'period');
str = str.replace(',', 'comma');
str = str.split(/[,. ]/);
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].indexOf('period') > -1) {
    str[i] = str[i].replace('period', '');
    str.splice(i+1, 0, ".");
  } else if (str[i].indexOf('comma') > -1) {
    str[i] = str[i].replace('comma', '');
    str.splice(i+1, 0, ",");
  }
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Run it and then compare to the result OP wants.

Comment: I'm aware that it removes the comma and period. However, it's sufficient for the reason that OP wants to use it for.

Comment: I only need to change the name, so I have to keep the comma and period on its original place.